# How do I make multiple API calls via XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript

I'm not that experienced when it comes to APIs so excuse me in advance.

I'm trying to get a button to display the contents (response) of an API, and the code below works wonders. I'm wondering how I would make the exact same request, but instead of the "explicit" endpoint, I want a "history" endpoint instead.

How would I do this?

```
const data = null;

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

var object1;



xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        object1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    }
    document.getElementById('thejoke').innerHTML = object1.value;
});







xhr.open("GET", "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=explicit");

xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to make it a function:

```
function send(category) {

    const url = "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category=" + category
    const data = null;

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

    var object1;



    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
            object1 = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
        document.getElementById('thejoke').innerHTML = object1.value;
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "");

    xhr.send(data);
}
```

And then you can you call it like this:

```
send("explicit");
```

The only problem you then face is that `object1` is not available outside of the function. You could work around this by making `object1` a global variable, or do the things you want to directly in the `EventListener`.

Comment: How would I declare object1 as a global variable in this case?

Comment: You could declare it outside of the function, or use window: https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-global-variable